# Access resource within the calling assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, resource-files

I'm moving some code from an application to a helper class project. This application uses resource files that hold texts and their translations.

Is there a way to still access the resource files from the application within that new helper project? This would be very helpful, because then i don't have to move half of those resource files to that new project.

Assembly A (contains the resource file)  ->  Calls method on Assembly B and this method needs a resource text from Assembly A.

Comment: Is there a reason that A cannot simply pass the resource to B in the function call?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetFile()** method in dll to get the file from application assembly and use ResourceManager class to load it. Or possibly use **Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetExportedTypes()** to get strongly typed resource class. However, you should consider if referencing resources in application from library is the right approach. I would suggest either moving all resources to library assembly and referencing them from application, or (probably the best) - create separate assembly only for resources and use it both from app and dll.